# A certain example of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Is there an example of a real rank $2$ $\{0,1\}$ matrix of $4\times 4$ size with every row distinct and no zero rows? How to prove there is none if there is no example?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Can you construct a $4 \times 2$ matrix with the same properties? (In particular, how many distinct $1 \times 2$ $(0, 1)$ matrices are there?)

**Hint for edited post** Pick two linearly independent rows of the matrix; since the rank of the matrix is $2$, all other rows are linearly combinations of these. Which linear combinations of the rows are nonzero and contain only $0$ and $1$ entries?

Comment: updated to correct post there.

Comment: I edited the post to give a hint for the updated version of the question.

Comment: please post one explicit example.

Comment: The conclusion of the reasoning in the hint is that there *aren't* any examples.

Comment: funny isn't it?